# Unable to install AWS SAM Cli on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I am trying to install AWS SAM Cli on my Mac because I am trying to learn the AWS services. But I have installed the AWS cli successful using bundle. But when I tried to install the AWS SAM Cli as well. But it is not working. This is what I have done so far.

Run this command

```
pip install --user aws-sam-cli
```

Everything went fine.

Then I opened and edited the ~/.bash_profile. This is the content of the .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.7/bin:$PATH
# Find your Python User Base path (where Python --user will install packages/scripts)
$ USER_BASE_PATH=$(python -m site --user-base)
# Update your preferred shell configuration
-- Standard bash --> ~/.bash_profile
-- ZSH           --> ~/.zshrc
export PATH=$PATH:$USER_BASE_PATH/bin
```

Then I closed the terminal and run sam --version.

It is saying command not found. What is wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 3):

The now recommended way to install SAM CLI is to use brew and honestly it's way better, saves you a lot of headaches, like the one you're facing now. See [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-mac.html#serverless-sam-cli-install-mac-homebrew) for details.